# Docker Container "Destination Port Unreachable" under ask4.com service

Tags: networking, docker

Currenlty I'm trying to set up network in my Docker Container, however what I get is - "Destination Port Unreachable". The thing is that I'm running this ask4.com provided connection (student accommodation) and it seems that it just blocks everything unless I actually sign in to my account in Docker container. In the meantime on my laptop I do have a proper connection.

[image]

Comment: what is giving you the error?

Comment: @grag42 `docker run -ti python:3.4 ping google.com`

Comment: if that fails out  provide the error here alon with  output of  netstat FROM the docker container please as it is likely a  host to docker  networking failure  if  dimazubrik's command fails out

Comment: I agree with linuxdev2013, That sounds like a networking issue.  From inside the docker, you can get an ipconfig, and route and post those?